# Failed to install metric-server on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to install metric-server in EKS. While applying manifest file. My pod status is in CrashLoopBackOff.

Manifest File URL: kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml

Logs output:

```
Error: failed to get delegated authentication kubeconfig: failed to get delegated authentication kubeconfig: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied
```

Pls help.

Comment: Im facing same issue. Did you get the answer ?